# Windows: Run batch/PowerShell script on startup with "highest privilege" but check for network share mounted for user

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I have a batch file which starts a PowerShell script, set on startup, via Windows Task Scheduler.

As the PowerShell script needs to stop a specific network card after running, it needs administrative privileges. So I checked the box "run with highest privileges".

The PowerShell script uses `Test-Path "filesystem::\\network-share\Test"` to check if the path is accessible. I also tried using the assigned drive letter directly. All is only run after logon, so the user which has access to the shared directory is already fully logged in.

Both fail to run at startup, even if the IP of the share is reachable. It works fine if I run the same with right-click "run as administrator".

I think it's because "run with highest privilege" is kind of independent of the logged-in user so has no access to the share drive?

I do not want to store the credentials for accessing the share drive within the script.

Comment: You are running the script in a context that is not the user context, thus a separate PS process, thus your potential catch22. You can also get user shares from here as well: ```HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\LanmanServer\Shares```.  To see native stuff via a script, the script must run in the user context.

Comment: You need to set registry value [EnableLinkedConnections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/networking/mapped-drives-not-available-from-elevated-command) to make network shares available when the current user runs _elevated_ (highest privileges).